# Extracting list of objects from API request response

Tags: python, json

I'm using an API call to retrieve JSON data, the response to the get request is formatted like this:

- `data`: JSON representation of resource requested
- `linked`: an object containing additional entities
- `meta`: miscellaneous information based on the endpoint.

When I do:

```
DictData = response.json()
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(DictData, indent = 2)
print(json_formatted_str)
```

I get all three sections (data, linked, meta):

```
{
 "meta": {}, 
 "linked": {}
 "data": [
    {
      "date_on_hold": null, 
      "cc": [], 
      "labels": [
        "Sales/Licensing"
      ], 
      "agent": 8, 
      "person": 210
    }
]
```

And when I do:

```
DictData = response.json()
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(DictData['data'], indent = 2)
print(json_formatted_str)
```

I specifically get the data section:

```
[
    {
      "date_on_hold": null, 
      "cc": [], 
      "labels": [
        "Sales/Licensing"
      ], 
      "agent": 8, 
      "person": 210
    }
]
```

How would I go about specifically extracting the `"person"` tuple in the `"data"` section? In this example, I would want to print out `'210'`.

I believe I'm getting a list of objects, and I'm currently printing out the `"data"` object, but how would I print/extract the `"person"` variable in the `"data"` object?

Comment: just do `DictData['data']['person']`

Comment: Use DictData['data'][0]['person']

Comment: Since the "data" key contains a list of dict, you have to mention the '0' to state its the first element inside

Comment: That did it! @nithin11 thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
json_dict["data"][0]["person"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since DictData['data'] is a list of 1 element, to get value of a single person you can do:

```
DictData['data'][0]['person']
```

In case you need to iterate over the data list you can do:

```
for element in DictData['data']:
    print(element['person'])
```